# how can return multiple result set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, repository-pattern

I am using asp.net(mvc4) application,also I have used the repository design pattern. I want to return multiple result set from store procedure to entity framework object.
Here is the code

```
    Alter PROCEDURE DDDDD
       @TicketID INT
         AS 
       SELECT * FROM XXXXX  WHERE TicketID= @TicketID
    SELECT * FROM YYYY WHERE TicketID= @TicketID
    END
 KeyValuePair<string, object>[] lstparam = new KeyValuePair<string, object>[1];
            lstparam[0] = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("TicketID", TicketID);
            var obj = _getTroubleTicketDetails_Result.ExecuteCustomStoredProc("DDDDD", lstparam);
            TroubleTicketDetails objDetails = new TroubleTicketDetails();
            objDetails.TicketDetails.AddRange(obj);
            return objDetails;
```

I want to have both result set in single sp call return by "DDDDD"

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but you should probably use a container or define a data structure/ class for that.

Comment: can you please elaborate more how can I create structure / class?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an ASP programmer, I can only give general advice.